# An entire function satisfying $\left|f\left(ne^{i\theta}\right)\right|\le e^{n\cos \theta}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let , $f$ be an entire function and $$\left|f\left(ne^{i\theta}\right)\right|\le e^{n\cos \theta}$$for all $n\ge 1$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. Show that $f(z)=Ce^z$ for some constant $C$ with $|C|\le 1$.

First I put $x=n\cos \theta$ and $y=n\sin \theta$. Then , $|f(x+iy)|\le e^x$. That is $$|f(z)|\le e^x=|e^z|.$$

Now consider the function $g(z)=e^{-z}f(z)$. Then $g$ is bounded and entire function and hence it is constant...Hence the proof is done...

Is the proof correct ?

Comment: I think you meant $g(z)=\exp(-z)\,f(z)$.  The rest is sound.

Comment: $|f(z)/e^z|<1$ for $|z|=n$ for all $n$.  Take $n \to \infty$ and apply Liouville's Theorem.